# Qual è il senso di "rappreso" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> Che dico potevano: su tutto era stesa la polvere del tempo,
>   non la polvere, la particolare opacità delle cose morte, dovunque
>   era il senso di gesti **rappresi** nell'aria; e, in una parola, come mi
>   era subito apparso che non altra mano dalla sua poteva avere in
>   tal modo disposti quegli oggetti, così ora tornai alla mia precedente supposizione, ora anzi per la prima volta acquistai bruscamente la certezza assoluta che ella era morta. E dappertutto era
>   profuso quel suo giallo leggermente abbrunato, come un bagno di
>   funebre oro.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "gesti rappresi" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato il verbo "rapprendere" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che vuol dire "coagularsi, indurirsi", quindi immagino che nel testo sia usato in modo figurato. Tuttavia, non sono sicura di aver colto il senso del termine "rappreso" nel brano sopra citato. Significa che c'era la sensazione di gesti fatti molto tempo fa che si erano "congelati" nel tempo?

Comment: Credo tu sia sulla strada giusta; secondo me il narratore vuole trasmettere che questi gesti sono stati talmente ripetuti del tempo da essersi "condensati" nell'aria e aver lasciato una traccia "visibile" (almeno a livello emozionale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI15/GDLI%2015%20ocr_499.pdf&parola=rappreso) appare appunto la citazione di Landolfi della domanda come esempio del seguente significato figurato del termine "rappreso":

> Figur. Immobilizzato, fissato (un gesto).

Answer (score -1):

Sì, in questo caso è usato come sinonimo di congelato (vedi "http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rapprendere/").

Comment: Se una risposta aggiungesse qualcosa a quello che è già detto nella domanda, sarebbe pure meglio. (Senza contare che “rappreso” non significa “congelato” e che “sì” si scrive con l'accento.)